# Como enviar anexo por e-mail no Moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

Estou tentando fazer desta forma, mas o anexo não é enviado, apenas o e-mail.

```
$fileName       = 'Arquivo'.date('d-m-Y H-i').'.xlsx';
$directory      = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/local/plugin/exports/'.$fileName;

# Envia e-mail para o supervisor
$userMail = $DB->get_record('user', ['id' => 2]);

email_to_user(
    $userMail, 
    $userMail, 
    'Assunto', 
    'Mensagem', 
    'Mensagem', 
    $directory, 
    $fileName
);
```

Usando o `email_to_user` é possível?

Comment: Acho que o nome do arquivo não poderia ter espaço `Arquivo15-03-2018 13-28.xlsx`.

Comment: Eu vou testar, hein!

Comment: Não funcionou. Você me enganou!

Comment: Óh! Já votaram negativo...! E nem mencionaram o motivo. Nem editaram se viram algo errado... Por essas e outras que...